# Android Native Dependency Management

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface

I have some native libraries to be integrated with my project in the form of .so files. My company has a rule that binaries should not be committed into the git repository, but instead be uploaded into our internal artifactory.

But I can't simply add the libraries into the dependencies block of gradle, since I still need to copy them to the designated native library folder. I'm seeking for a solution that enable me to do build automation, so ideally the libraries would be resolved and copied to the right folder before compilation start, and I want it to be configurable, since the default native lib folder can be changed anyway.

Comment: That is an okay solution, though I'm still hoping I don't need to maintain separate project for the AAR.